# Regarding User Interface: Target tracking and time in motion studies

Tags: javascript, css, html, tracking, usability

I was wondering if anyone knew how to or if it is possible to track mouse cursor movements, button clicks, and click times to a off site database just using CSS, HTML5 and Javascript? I ask this regarding usability studies.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript or JQuery can be used to track mouse position, but you would need PHP to send the information to a database. Check out [this article](http://css-tricks.com/tracking-clicks-building-a-clickmap-with-php-and-jquery/).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you just use an off-the-shelf product instead of creating your own.  Search around for heatmaps.  The biggest one is CrazyEgg, but it's not free.  Check out [this site](http://www.paulolyslager.com/heatmap-hot-or-not/) for a comparison of other alternatives, including free options.